# SQL wildcard not producing any results

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

I guess there should be a rather simple explanation for this, but I can't come up with any idea.

This query works as expected (result = 1 row):

```html
SELECT Sites.Master_ID AS Master_ID, Scopes.Name AS Scope, Brands.Extension AS [Brand], Sites.ID AS [Site ID], Sites.Name AS [Site Name], Sites.Address, Sites.CAP, Sites.City, Countries.Name AS Country
FROM Sites
INNER JOIN Scopes ON Sites.scope_ID = Scopes.ID INNER JOIN Brands ON Sites.brand_ID = Brands.ID
INNER JOIN Countries ON Sites.country_ID = Countries.ID
WHERE 'BA001' IN (Scopes.Name, Brands.Extension, Sites.ID, Sites.Name, CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),Sites.Address), Sites.CAP, Sites.City, Countries.Name)
```

While adding the wildcard it's not (result = 0 row):

```html
SELECT Sites.Master_ID AS Master_ID, Scopes.Name AS Scope, Brands.Extension AS [Brand], Sites.ID AS [Site ID], Sites.Name AS [Site Name], Sites.Address, Sites.CAP, Sites.City, Countries.Name AS Country
FROM Sites
INNER JOIN Scopes ON Sites.scope_ID = Scopes.ID INNER JOIN Brands ON Sites.brand_ID = Brands.ID
INNER JOIN Countries ON Sites.country_ID = Countries.ID
WHERE '%BA001%' IN (Scopes.Name, Brands.Extension, Sites.ID, Sites.Name, CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),Sites.Address), Sites.CAP, Sites.City, Countries.Name)
```

Am I using the wildcards the proper way?

Looking forward to your reply.
Many thanks.

PS: I'm launching the query from SQL Server Management Studio 18.4

Comment: `IN` does not work with wildcards. You need to use `LIKE` operator. And the way you need it needs to be each field with an `OR` or you concatenate everything and use like on it.

Comment: If you don't use the wildcards with the operator LIKE then they are not wildcards, they are just characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards work with `LIKE`, not `IN`.

You could concatenate the values together:

```
WHERE CONCAT(Scopes.Name, Brands.Extension, Sites.ID, Sites.Name, CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),Sites.Address), Sites.CAP, Sites.City, Countries.Name) LIKE '%BA001%'
```

You might want to include delimiters:

```
WHERE CONCAT_WS('|', Scopes.Name, Brands.Extension, Sites.ID, Sites.Name, CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),Sites.Address), Sites.CAP, Sites.City, Countries.Name) LIKE '%BA001%'
```

`CONCAT_WS()` was introduced in SQL Server 2017.